# Tetrahedron subdivision

Tags: geometry, numerical-methods, computational-geometry

What are all the possible subdivisions of the P3 tetrahedron (i.e. for each face, 3 vertices plus two points per edge, located at 1/3 and 2/3, and the centroïd of the face, so a total of 20 points for the tetrahedron), by P1 tetrahedrons ?
Or could someone give some reference, where it has already be done ?

Comment: Welcome to this site! Notice that your post contains no question, just a statement of fact.  What is it, precisely, that you wish to know? What do you already understand, where are you stuck? These informations will allow the readers to provide a precise answer.  As it stands now, your post looks like it is asking users to do an exercise in your stead; posts like this are usually not well received.

Comment: Transformed formally into a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do the "obvious" thing of forming P1 tetrahedrons similar to the original tetrahedron whenever possible, you end up making a P1 for each of the original 4 corner vertices, and a P1 for each of the middle segments of the 6 edges. The remaining volume is 4 similar octahedrons. You can apply any tetrahedralization of an octahedron to split them up (e.g. into 4 tets circling around one diagonal), or you can add a vertex in its center and make 8 tets that emanate from the central vertex (these may be more nicely shaped).